# How can I find the index of the second-to-last occurrence of a value in an array?

Tags: c++

For example if I have an array like `[1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0, 5, 7]` the most recent occurrence of the element 5 will be at the 4th index (considering the array is indexed from 1 onwards).

Comment: How would you do it by hand?  Once yo have that, turn that process into code.

Comment: What about looping from the back of the collection and taking the second occurrence?

Comment: @Jayden Nightshade Are you trying to find the position of the second occurrence of 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Naive method:

1. Have two variables, `matchingIndex` and `lastMatchingIndex` (initialise them to -1 or something obvious)
2. Loop through the array
3. When you encounter a match, move `matchingIndex` to `lastMatchingIndex`, then put the current index into `matchingIndex`
4. Once you've reached the end, `lastMatchingIndex` contains the index you want (0-based!) unless it's -1, which means there weren't two matches

More elegant method:

1. Have two variables, `matchingIndex` and `numMatches` (initialising the latter to 0)
2. Loop *backwards* through the array
3. When you encounter a match, put the current index into `matchingIndex` and increment `numMatches`
4. If `numMatches` is 2, stop.
5. If `numMatches` isn't 2 when you reach the beginning of the array, there weren't two matches so there is no result

I think you'll admit that this is actually quite straightforward. You're literally just recording and counting matches then stopping when you get the one you want.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v{1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0, 5, 7};
    const int searchFor = 5;

    int matchingIndex = -1;
    int numMatches = 0;

    for (int i = v.size()-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (v[i] == searchFor)
        {
            numMatches++;
            matchingIndex = i;

            if (numMatches == 2)
                break;  // no point continuing!
        }
    }

    if (numMatches == 2)
        std::cout << "Found second-to-last instance of '" << searchFor << "' at index " << matchingIndex << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "No matches, or only one match\n";
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d156c84b852b8b3))

Version using algorithms:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> v{1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 0, 0, 5, 7};
    const int searchFor = 5;

    // First match from end
    auto it = std::find(std::rbegin(v), std::rend(v), searchFor);

    // Second match from end
    if (it != std::rend(v))
        it = std::find(it+1, std::rend(v), searchFor);

    if (it != std::rend(v))
        std::cout << "Found second-to-last instance of '" << searchFor << "' at index " << std::distance(std::begin(v), it.base()) << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "No matches, or only one match\n";
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e56d3a27f4a64ed6))